# EditText is hidden under the keyboard , In the navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have some `EditText`s inside the `Navigation Drawer` , But when the keyword is coming up it cover the `EditText`.

I tried the following code inside the activity definition of `Manifest` but the issue not fixed.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Any suggestin ?

Answer (score 0):

The `windowSoftInputMode` flag only works for Activities, which is not the case of a Navigation Drawer.

You can try to calculate the keyboard's height to manually move the `EditText` above it by using a `GlobalLayoutListener`: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265) for a concrete example.